# composer better way to load repository without packagist

Tags: php, json, composer-php

I am trying to load my own PHP library which is not registered on packagist.org, just only in my public origin/master on github.com.

Look at my **project compser.json** and my first step:

```
"name": "jzapletal/wakers-cms",
"description": "Wakers MVC CMS based on Nette Framework",
"type": "project",
"license": ["MIT"],
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "jzaplet/nette-asset-loader",
            "version": "0.9",
            "source": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "https://github.com/jzaplet/nette-asset-loader.git",
                "reference": "master"
            },
        }
    }
],

"require": {
    "php": "^7.0",
    "nette/nette": "2.4.0",
    "milo/vendor-versions": "^1.1",
    "jzaplet/nette-asset-loader": "^0.9"
},

"minimum-stability": "stable"
```

But it does not works. It does not generate classmap and require dependencies from this library. I think that **[composer.json file for this library](https://github.com/jzaplet/nette-asset-loader/blob/master/composer.json)** is totaly ignored, composer just load source codes.

After this I try to load dependencies and classmap directly from my **project composer.json** file, and it works.

```
{
"name": "jzapletal/wakers-cms",
"description": "Wakers MVC CMS based on Nette Framework",
"type": "project",
"license": ["MIT"],
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "jzaplet/nette-asset-loader",
            "version": "0.9",
            "source": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "https://github.com/jzaplet/nette-asset-loader.git",
                "reference": "master"
            },
            "require": {
                "php": ">= 5.6",
                "oyejorge/less.php": "^v1.7",
                "matthiasmullie/minify": "^1.3",
                "leafo/scssphp": "^0.6.3",
                "nette/finder": "^2.4",
                "nette/utils": "^2.4",
                "nette/di": "^2.4"
            },
            "autoload": {
                "classmap": [
                    "src/"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
],

"require": {
    "php": "^7.0",
    "nette/nette": "2.4.0",
    "milo/vendor-versions": "^1.1",
    "jzaplet/nette-asset-loader": "^0.9"
},

"minimum-stability": "stable"
```

But I think it is not best way. I want to specify dependencies, classmap and etc. **only in library composer.json**.

Is it possible?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12957929/310726

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use PHP composer to clone git repo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954051/use-php-composer-to-clone-git-repo)