# Github InvalidArgumentException new library

Tags: php, git, laravel, github

I am creating my first library for Laravel Framework in github, and after the `push` step, i try to get the library via composer:

`composer require malekbenelouafi/laravel-status`

But, i always get this error:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   Could not find package malekbenelouafi/laravel-status at any version
>   for your minimum-stability (dev). Check the package spelling or your
>   minimum-stability

This is the link of my library in github :

https://github.com/malekbenelouafi/laravel-status

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project isn't a composer package, it's only on Github. Composer is separate from Github and you'll have to publish your package on an aggregator like Packagist.

Go to the [Packagist](https://packagist.org/) website and check out the instructions for "Publishing Packages".

Alternatively, if you're not ready or wanting to publish the library as a package, you should be able to modify your `composer.json` to handle this without publishing.

Basically, you just need to add the Github repo to the `composer.json` as such:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "url": "https://github.com/malekbenelouafi/laravel-status.git",
            "type": "git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        // Other required libraries
    }
}
```

You can read more about this option [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12957929/5475560) and [in Composer's docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs). Thanks to @Alex Harris for his answer below.

Answer (score 2):

@John-Michael L'Aller is correct you do not have a package. You should however, be able to modify your `composer.json` to handle this without publishing your repo as a package. You can read more about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14485706/1561929.

Comment: Good point. I figured the end goal was to share the library, but I'll add this to my answer for future readers.