# Could not add composer dependency of own github repo

Tags: git, github, composer-php

Any idea why the composer is throwing error of:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find a matching version of package divix1988/laminas-smarty-module. Check the package spelling, your vers
  ion constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable).
```

When trying to add my own new dependency via: 
`composer require divix1988/laminas-smarty-module` ?

https://github.com/divix1988/laminas-smarty-module

Comment: Seems like you are trying to add a private package, typically they need to be in packagist. Here are a couple of resources on it.
https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md
https://barryvanveen.nl/blog/55-installing-a-private-package-with-composer

Comment: How **exactly** did you configure all that? I haven't found your package on Packagist

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use PHP composer to clone git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954051/use-php-composer-to-clone-git-repo)

Comment: Thank you @NicoHaase you are right, I need to add it to packagist first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways:

- add it to Packagist: https://packagist.org/packages/submit
- add it's URL in `composer.json`, like:

```
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@github.com:divix1988/laminas-smarty-module.git"
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a package via composer you have to add it to packagist before. Login packagist from [here](https://packagist.org/login/) and then add your package. When your package is presente on packagist, you can require it using composer.